# Set alarm every 2 hour display on (Mac)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, alarm

I intend to save my eyes healthy. So, i want to set alarm every 2 hour computer i used. I have tried to set on calender and clock, but i can't find the way.

Answer (score 2):

if you have macOS Catalina, in Reminders App, you can create a reminder that alerts you every 2 hours, for example.

for another, you have free apps in Mac AppStore like for https://apps.apple.com/us/app/time-out-break-reminders/id402592703?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mojave, and if you work for say 10 hours, you can set up five recurring reminders like this: or by telling to Siri:

[image: recurring reminders ss]

I know it's clunky but works if working hours are fixed and less.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a simple command which can be run on Mac Terminal:

```
while true; do osascript -e 'display notification "Save your eyes!!!" with title "2 Hrs Reminder"'; sleep 7200; done;
```

Press `ctrl` + `c` to stop receiving reminders.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is perfectly working solution and inline with question context.